# How can I run two unicorn environments in same ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, unicorn

I have a AngularJS (front-end) running on Nginx and Rails API (backend) running on Unicorn in an Ubuntu EC2 instance.

Rails API integrates with some other platforms such as Paypal and other services, so I have some configuration properties that may have different values depending on the environment.

In the other hand, Im trying to deploy two different environments in the same EC2 instance (in different paths).

I have no problem with the AngularJS Nginx part. I have two servers pointing to different paths. But the problem is when I start Unicorn, I start it in one environment mode (test or production) and I need both environments up and running at same time. Is it possible? Should I start two unicorn server?

Is there any better approach?

```
   **UPDATE**
```

This is my config/unicorn.rb file (I dont know what it does, I copied from somewhere).

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 2)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

and this is my Nginx sites-available/default:

```
server {

        root /home/ubuntu/test/apps/domain/app;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name www.test.domain.com;
}

server {

    server_name www.domain.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/production/apps/domain/app;
}
```

The Nginx web servers are working ok, but what I want is www.test.domain.com redirects to a unicorn started in test environment, and www.domain.com redirects to the unicorn production environment (maybe listening in different ports).

I dont have any other Nginx configuration.

Comment: Unicorn is application server, it serves application. Each application you need to serve, you should start a different instance, on different port or socket. They can run at the same time, no problem at all, unless you tell them to start on the same resource (port/socket), in which case it will not start at all

Comment: @RubyRacer just to confirm we are on the same page. These both applications should run in a different environment. So, one unicorn should run on test and the other one in production. Is this possible? If so, could you please give me some more details on how to do it. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

When unicorn starts, it creates 3 "locks". One, is the process id file, the second is the socket file and the third is the tcp port the server listens to.

So, let's suppose you start you application in production environment like this:

```
unicorn_rails -E production -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

The next this you have to do is:

```
cp config/unicorn.rb config/unicorn_test.rb
```

Then, edit the new file and change these lines (example values, but you get the picture), if they are defined:

```
pid APP_PATH + "/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid" # change to another pid
[..]
listen APP_PATH + "/tmp/pids/.unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64 # use antother .sock
listen 8080, :tcp_nopush => true # use another port
```

Then, you must copy your nginx server configuration to point to the new application. Same root, different socket, different port, whichever it uses.

Finally:

```
unicorn_rails -E test -c config/unicorn_test.rb -D
```

Comment: I have updated the post above with my Nginx and Unicorn configuration files. I have some questions. I understand for your answer what I should do is to copy my current config/unicorn.rb (above) and add those 3 lines you have attached above. My question is I dont have anything similar in my previous production file. Is it ok? My second question ir related to your comment:  "you must copy your nginx server configuration to point to the new application". I have added my nginx sites-available file. I think I dont have any other config file. I dont have anything related to unicorn configuration.